# Soundcard unloaded

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa

I cant play any sound on Ubuntu. Its not hardware related as everything is working on a parallel Windows installation...
Probably its because I played around setting up an icecast server and in the process I accidentally removed a wrong pulseaudio module. Sadly I didnt realize immediatly and now I dont know which one I removed. How can I get the sound back?

```
from lshw:
  *-multimedia UNCLAIMED
       description: Audio device
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 1f.3
       bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.3
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: iomemory:600-5ff iomemory:600-5ff memory:604b118000-604b11bfff memory:604b000000-604b0fffff
```

```
$ cat /proc/asound/cards 
 1 [Loopback       ]: Loopback - Loopback
                      Loopback 1
```

```
$ pactl list modules short
0   module-device-restore       
1   module-stream-restore       
2   module-card-restore     
3   module-augment-properties       
4   module-switch-on-port-available     
5   module-switch-on-connect        
6   module-udev-detect      
7   module-alsa-card    device_id="1" name="platform-snd_aloop.0" card_name="alsa_card.platform-snd_aloop.0" namereg_fail=false tsched=yes fixed_latency_range=no ignore_dB=no deferred_volume=yes use_ucm=yes avoid_resampling=no card_properties="module-udev-detect.discovered=1"    
8   module-native-protocol-unix     
9   module-default-device-restore       
10  module-always-sink      
11  module-intended-roles       
12  module-suspend-on-idle      
13  module-console-kit      
14  module-systemd-login        
15  module-position-event-sounds        
16  module-role-cork        
17  module-snap-policy      
18  module-filter-heuristics        
19  module-filter-apply     
20  module-x11-publish  display=:0 xauthority=/run/user/1001/gdm/Xauthority 
21  module-x11-cork-request display=:0 xauthority=/run/user/1001/gdm/Xauthority 
22  module-x11-xsmp display=:0 xauthority=/run/user/1001/gdm/Xauthority session_manager=local/XPS:@/tmp/.ICE-unix/1914,unix/XPS:/tmp/.ICE-unix/1914
```

Comment: You've not mentioned what Ubuntu product you're using, nor what release.  Did you remove a package?  (*if so your command history, or `apt` package history will tell you what you removed*), or just unload a module (*command history should tell you*), so have you look in logs for your *unstated* Ubuntu product/release, as those details will be easiest to reverse whatever you did.

Comment: Im using Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS. I unloaded a module but I did it by indicating the module number... so I dont know which one it was :(